# DataGrid does not properly bind to DataGrid if AutoGenerateColumns is false

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datatable

I've been driving myself nuts with this and I'm hoping I'm just missing something obvious.

I have a `DataGrid` I want to bind to an in-memory `DataTable`. With AutoGenerateColumns set to true, I can edit the fields and have the changes propagate to the datatable and everything is great. The problem is that I wanted to have a Drop-down combobox for the 'Status' field. I then set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and manually added the column headers in XAML. When I do this I can no longer edit the fields and have the changes persist, instead each field is blank after I click away. I checked the status of the Datagrid columns during debugging and found that the bindings are reading as null. Any ideas of what I've done wrong?

XAML Code:

```
<DataGrid Margin="31,29,0,29" Name="dgTickets" RowEditEnding="dgTickets_RowEditEnding" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID #" x:Name="ID" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer Name" x:Name="CustomerName" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone #" x:Name="Phone"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Status" x:Name="Status"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Bool?" x:Name="bool1"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Bool?" x:Name="bool2"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Bool?" x:Name="bool3"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes" x:Name="Notes"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

My C# code for creating the DataTable and associating it:

```
    //add columns
        column = new DataColumn("ID", System.Type.GetType("System.String")); //two piece constructor - adds header string and data type
        dbTable.Columns.Add(column); //adds the column to the table

        column = new DataColumn("CustomerName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dbTable.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn("Phone#", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dbTable.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn("Status", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

        dbTable.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn("bool1", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        dbTable.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn("bool2", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        dbTable.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn("bool3", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        dbTable.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn("Notes", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dbTable.Columns.Add(column);
        //add rows
        row = dbTable.NewRow(); 

        dbTable.Rows.Add(row); 

        dbTable.AcceptChanges();
        dgTickets.ItemsSource = dbTable.DefaultView;
```

Any advice is appreciated. I've tried several different ways to get these two elements to work together, but I can't seem to get two to bind properly if the headers are manually defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to throw the bindings in there, eg:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer Name" x:Name="CustomerName" Binding={Binding path=CustomerName} />
```

Comment: That worked fantastically. I definitely need to pick up a book on the subject. Thank you!